# HTTPS for SharePoint Deployments

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, https

Do all deployments of SharePoint (Intranet, Extranet and Internet) require HTTPS or only Extranet and Internet scenarios require it? Can any MVP or an MS person please respond, possibly with some reference links?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no requirement for HTTPS, however your information security people may have something to say if you decide to publish, say, an extranet externally without using HTTPS!

This really is down to your information security policies. In general, it is strongly recommended that instances published externally are secured using HTTPS as this ensures that all traffic to/from the servers is encrypted, which means that traffic cannot in general be inspected or intercepted. If you are happy with HTTP traffic only, and accept the risks that this brings of the traffic being intercepted, then there is nothing stopping you from implementing external access over HTTP only.

In addition to using HTTPS for your traffic to/from the SharePoint servers, I'd also very strongly recommend implementing a reverse proxy through which traffic at the edge of your network should flow to provide additional protection. Note that you can use a combination of ADFS and Web Application Proxy, provided as part of Windows Server 2012/R2 for this, and it works well.

Information on Microsoft's best practices for extranet deployments can be found at [https://technet.microsoft.com](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204611(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

At large SSL is not requirement for the SharePoint but there are certains area where one should have SSL.

1. If you plan to use ADFS authentication
2. Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) is a requirement for web applications that are deployed in scenarios that support server-to-server authentication and app authentication.
3. Configure Exchange task synchronization also require SSL.

http://corypeters.net/2013/03/ssl-and-sharepoint-2013/